# Is it possible to get a text that is between numbers and letters?

Tags: c#, letters-and-numbers

if you can get a text that is between numbers and letters
example:

¸¶¹¹,example⌐╙∙√∞∟

Well, the word "example" is changed to a textbox .. Obviously I would put between what has to be the word and in this case is:

¸¶¹¹, and ⌐╙∙√∞∟

Greetings and Thanks

Sorry for my bad English, I speak Spanish

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you'll have a string with mixed numbers and letters.  Using the regular string functions will still work.  They won't care what the characters in the string represent.  For instance:

```
        string MyString = "¸¶¹¹,example⌐╙∙√∞∟";
        if(MyString.Contains("example"))
        {
            MyString = MyString.Replace("example","and");
        }
```

MyString = "¸¶¹¹,and⌐╙∙√∞∟" after the replace method is called.

Comment: but as would be the other way around?, I want you to see what is between 1234 and 5678 (is randomly generated in the program I'm doing) :L